# How does virtualization handle modern TLBs?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-hardware, virtual-memory

In an answer to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/94226/how-does-the-tlb-identify-a-particular-process) question:

> For instance, modern Intel TLBs have a process context ID (PCID); each TLB entry is tagged with the PCID of the process that the page mapping is for, and the processor will only use that TLB entry if its PCID matches the ID of the currently running process. The processor fills the PCID when it creates the TLB entry from a register which the operating system must set to a unique value for each process. You can read about that more by searching for PCID.

How does virtualization (one host OS and multiple guest OSes) handle modern TLBs?

If there was only the host OS, there would be no problem. But when there is host OS (hypervisor) and guest OSes, there can be processes with same PCID across OSes. The Hypervisor might create a virtual TLB and do its own management somehow. There are possibilities, but what is it that  actually happens?

Comment: @D.W. I added a paragraph. Is my question clearer now?

Comment: Awesome!  Much clearer.  Thanks!